# find out the enable/disable status of active directory users

Tags: node.js, active-directory

Using this code I'm able to extract all AD users' information:

```
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');

    var ad = new ActiveDirectory({ url: 'ldap://domain.com',
                               baseDN: 'dc=domain,dc=com',
                               username: 'user@domain.com',
                               password: 'password',
                               attributes: {
                                 user: [ 'givenName', 'mail', 'mobile' ],
                                //  group: [ 'anotherCustomAttribute', 'objectCategory' ]
                               }
                              });
ad.findUsers(function(err, users) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }
 
  if ((! users) || (users.length == 0)) console.log('No users found.');
  else {
    console.log('findUsers: '+JSON.stringify(users));
  }
});
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to find out which user is enabled or disabled. I know that there is an attribute called `UserAccountControl`  whose value means:

```
512=Enabled
514= Disabled
66048 = Enabled, password never expires
66050 = Disabled, password never expires
```

but I found some users whose `UserAccountControl` value is different from these values.

I've also heard of ms-DS-User-Account-Disabled, but I can't find it in the attribute list of users. So, how can I know if a user is enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [ms-DS-User-Account-Disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-msds-useraccountdisabled) indicates that it was only supported on ADAM (Active Directory Application Mode), but also the later [AD LDS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/adam/active-directory-lightweight-directory-services) (Lightweight Directory Services), as indicated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/adam/directory-services-api-element-differences#:%7E:text=msDS%2DUserAccountDisabled).

Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS), which is likely what you have, uses `userAccountControl`.

The [`userAccountControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-useraccountcontrol) attribute is a bit flag, meaning that each bit (`0` or `1`) in the binary value is a flag that means something (`1` is on and `0` is off). The decimal representation of all those bits could be all kinds of values, so you've found. So ignore the decimal value.

The second bit is the flag for "disabled". If the second bit is `1`, the account is disabled. That's what you want to find.

So get the value of the `userAccountControl` attribute, then use the [bitwise AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND) operator (`&`) to determine if the second bit is set:

```
var isDisabled = (userAccountControl & 2) === 2;
```

The parentheses in that are important, otherwise the order of operations isn't what you need.